# How to calculate number of changes of status for customer

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset (example)

```
        ID  MOnth  Status
    0   101  01    1
    1   101  02    1
    2   101  03    2
    3   101  04    1
    4   101  05    2
```

So if I want to calculate number of different statuses for this `ID` during 5 months, I can use the following :

`grouped=df['Status'].groupby(df['ID'])`

and then

`grouped.nunique()`
or  I can use a similar code:

```
df.groupby(['ID'])['Status'].nunique()
```

But the question is: how can I calculate the number of changing the statuses for `ID`. In this situation, there are 4 changes of statuses for ID during 5 Months

Comment: Aren't there only 3 changes of status? From 1 to 2, 2 to 1 and then 1 to 2 again?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the first status as also a status change, you can use a comparison of current period with previous period:

```py
df['status_change'] = (~(df['Status'] == df.groupby('ID')['Status'].shift(1))).astype(int)

Out[1]: 
    ID  MOnth  Status  status_change
0  101      1       1              1
1  101      2       1              0
2  101      3       2              1
3  101      4       1              1
4  101      5       2              1
```

Then to see the total changes, group it:

```py
df.groupby('ID').agg({'status_change': 'sum'})

Out[1]: 
     status_change
ID                
101              4
```

Answer (score 1):

We `apply` a condition to a groupby then return the value with a boolean and sum the consecutive values with a cumulative sum.

```
df["changes"] = df.groupby("ID")["Status"].apply(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift())).cumsum()


print(df)
    ID  Month  Status  changes
0  101      1       1        1
1  101      2       1        1
2  101      3       2        2
3  101      4       1        3
4  101      5       2        4
```

if you need to get the change in an aggregation you can use `last` to get the final change.